# Get the general solution for this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As I am not very familiarized whit differential equations (I'm more from algebra), I don't know how to solve this problem, but I need to understand how it's done because I have to explain it to a friend. I hope anyone could help me.

> Calculate the general solution of the next differential equation:
>   $$yF(xy)dx=xG(xy)dy $$

By other side, I want to ask too where can I find a book to understand how to do this kind of problems.

Comment: Are $x,y$ independent variables? Or is $y$ a function of $x$? What are $F,G$?

Comment: My friend got this problem from here: http://www.math.cinvestav.mx/sites/default/files/examenes/mayo05.pdf I suppose that F,G are functions and $x,y$ are independent.

Answer (score 4):

There is the following "well-known" differential equation:

> $$yF(xy)dx+xG(xy)dy=0$$

This is very similar to the differential equation that you have provided in that we have instead $yF(xy)dx-xG(xy)dy=0$.

Whenever $F\neq G$ we have the integrating factor

> $$\mu=\dfrac{1}{xy(F(xy)-G(xy))}$$

With the integrating factor, we arrive at an implicit solution, with a substitution $u=xy$:

> $$\ln(x)=\int\dfrac{G(u)du}{u(G(u)-F(u))}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Any introductory text on differential equations should have the basics.  Of course, you will be expected to have some experience with Algebra and Calculus so that looking at a problem with "F(xy)" and "G(xy)" you immediately think "hmm, looks like the substitution u= xy would be worth trying".  If u= xy then  $y= u/x so dy= du/x- udx/x^2$. The equation $yF(xy)dx= xG(xy)dy$ becomes $(u/x)F(u)dx= xG(u)(du/x- udx/x^2)$.  That is the same as $uF(u)du= xG(u)du- uG(u)dx$ so $(uF(u)- xG(u))du= -uG(u)dx$.

Comment: No, you should have $uFdx$ not $uFdu$